# 「将棋がお強いと伺いましたが」「いやあ、人に自慢するほどじゃありませんが、始めてもう40年になりますね。」

Tags: grammar, meaning

> A: 将棋がお強いと伺いましたが。
> B: いやあ、人に自慢するほどじゃありませんが、始めてもう40年になりますね。

First, I have problems determining the meaning of 伺う. Does it mean "to ask" or "to be told" here?

Second, I just learned about the comparisons with ほど.
There are two patterns I learned:

> 八ヶ岳は有名な山だが、富士山ほど有名ではない。

and

> 田中さんほど仕事がよくできる人はいません。

Now, in context of the dialogue in question, I think that pattern 1 is at play here.
Still, considering that I don't really know what the first sentence says, I wonder what to make of this. I also can't find what いやあ means.

Here's my attempt at translation:

> A: Have you been told that you're strong at shougi?
> B:  ? , while I don't boast towards people like that, for the first time already become 40 years.

I also can't make much sense of the second part in the second sentence either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, I have problems determining the meaning of 伺う. Does it mean "to ask" or "to be told" here?

(～と)伺う here is the humble form (謙譲語) of (～と)聞く, meaning "I heard that~~".
 <sub>～か伺った or ～～かと伺った would be "I asked whether~~."</sub>

> Second, I just learned about the comparisons with ほど.
>   八ヶ岳は有名な山だが、富士山ほど有名ではない。
>   田中さんほど仕事がよくできる人はいません。

ほど basically means "to the extent (that~)" or "to the (same) extent (as~)". So 富士山**ほど**有名ではない literally means "not famous *to the same extent as* Mt. Fuji", hence "is not so famous as Mt. Fuji", and 田中さん**ほど**よくできる人 means "a person who is competent *to the same extent as* Mr. Tanaka".

And here in your example 人に自慢するほどじゃありません, the ほど also means "to the extent (that~)."

> ［私の将棋の腕前は］人に自慢する**ほど**じゃありません。
>   *lit.*［My shogi technique is］not (good) *to the extent* that I can boast to others.
>   I am not good at shogi to the extent that I can boast about it to others.

> I also can't find what いやあ means.

It's an interjection (感動詞):

> いや〘感〙
>   驚き・感動・嘆きなどを表す語。**いやあ**。
>   「いや、びっくりした。」「いや、すばらしい。」
>   (明鏡国語辞典)

> 始めてもう40年になりますね。

始めて here is not "for the first time" (初めて)*, but the te-form of the verb 始める, *lit.* "started and~" → "since I started". 「～～して+ (period of time) +になる」 means "(period of time) has passed since ~~" or "It's been (period of time) since ~~."

"It's already been 40 years since I started (shogi)."

<sub>*始めて = [はじめて]{LHHH}, 初めて(for the first time) = [はじめて]{LHLL}</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The sentence means that

> A: I heard that you are very good at playing shogi.
> B: No, I am not so good that I could boast to anyone, but it's been 40 years since the first time I played.