# About ...ほど constructions

Tags: grammar, particle-ほど

Here, I already asked about a sentence containing a ほど construction, and chocolate was so kind to give me a nice, comprehensive answer :=)
("[Issues with this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52228/issues-with-this-sentence/52252#52252)")

However, a follow up question came to my mind now, which might even sound a bit silly:
In my textbook, ほど constructions are always used in that way:

> インフルエンザの予防注射は思っていたほど痛くなかったです。
>   Concerning the Influenza immunisation, it didn't hurt to the extent that I thought.

The keypoint: After ほど, a negation follows. And it's always like that in my textbook. "it **didn't**...to the extent..."

Is it possible for ほど constructions to be followed by a positive statement as well?
Like: "Concerning the influenza immunisation, it did hurt to the extent that I thought"?
Or are other constructions used for this kind of statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes ほど can be safely used in positive sentences, but it means something more like "to the point where ～" or "so ～ that ～".

Examples:

> - 目に見えるほど大きい。 It is big enough to be visible to the eye.
> - びっくりするほど高かった。 It was surprisingly expensive.
> - 眠れないほど嬉しいです。 I am too happy to sleep.
> - インフルエンザの予防接種は泣き叫ぶほど痛かった。
>     The flu shot was so painful that I (almost) cried.