# What does 気が遠くなるほど mean?

Tags: grammar, translation

> 神々は何度も何度も何度も, 気が遠くなるほどサイコロを振りました.

Having hard time fully understanding this sentence. Especially this part 「気が遠くなるほど」, or how it affects 「気が遠くなる」. My translation would be something along the lines of "Over and over and over again, the gods are astounded​ as they role the dice."

I would really appreciate it, if someone could break the sentence down a little bit and explain the grammar part, that I might have missed.

Comment: Have you tried the other meaning of 気が遠くなる? I can't be sure without more context, but I suspect it makes more sense here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 気が遠くなるほどサイコロを振りました

The construction is explained in this answer: "[About ...ほど constructions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52300/7810)" that it literally means "they rolled the dice to the degree that you (almost) feel faint".

Actually, 気が遠くなる is a very common metaphor in Japanese that depicts how overwhelming the scale/number is (imagine that you count sheep over and over, and you will soon fall unconscious). Here the referent is a number, so you can just translate it like:

> They rolled the dice for countless times.

cf.

> 気が遠くなるほど長い時間 *a nearly-eternal time*
>   気が遠くなるほど低い確率 *an incredibly low probability*
>   気が遠くなる事業 *a gargantuan project*

Answer (score 3):

For the usage of this ほど, see: [About ...ほど constructions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52300/5010)

Jisho.org treats 気が遠くなる [as if it had two meanings](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%B0%97%E3%81%8C%E9%81%A0%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B), but there is actually only one base meaning for this idiom, "to have the feeling of faintness/blackout", "to almost faint", "to be half-unconscious", etc. As you know, this can happen both when you are very sleepy/bored and when you are very shocked. In this case, it's the former; Gods rolled a dice for countless times to the point where it's difficult to keep consciousness or sanity.

Compare the idiom with 気を失う which is "to be (completely) unconscious", "to (fully) faint".