# What does 「ほど」 mean here?

Tags: meaning

Below is the lyrics from the song "[letter song](https://zh.moegirl.org.cn/Letter_song)"

> 好きな人と歩いた場所も
>
> その時見た景色も
>
> 振り返らず
>
> 今を駆け抜け
>
> 私は何と出会うの
>
> 立ち止まる**ほど**
>
> 意味を問う**ほど**
>
> きっとまだ大人ではなくて
>
> 今見てるもの　今出会う人
>
> その中でただ前だけを見てる

I want to know what does ほど mean here? Does it mean "the more ... the more ..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this ほど means "to the point where ～" or "enough to ～". It's [this ほど](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52302/5010), and is interchangeable with くらい/ぐらい.

> 立ち止まるほど、意味を問うほど、きっとまだ大人ではなくて
>
> I'm not yet old enough to stop or reflect on the meanings (of everything I come across) ...

Basically these lines are saying "I am too young to look back at what I have experienced".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems songs always reverse the normal order, and it makes it more difficult to understand.

Comment: @古手梨花 The prosaic version would be "きっと私はまだ、立ち止まったり意味を問うたりするほど大人ではない".