# Can から be omitted in てから?

Tags: て-form

In this sentence:
"Toukyou ni hikkoshite, go-nen ni naru, "
=> Since moving to Tokyo, it has been [it comes out to] five years.

From this site:
https://www.satorireader.com/articles/sanzu-no-kawa-episode-2-edition-m

て-form is interpreted as if it was てから. Is this possible, and if so, usual?
I do see て-form quite frequently when sequencing actions and/or indicating a causality (e.g. 家族に会えなくて、寂しいです). But so far, when explicitely expressing "since" から had always been used. 
It would be nice if someone could explain this phenomenon above, or at least point me to some ressources :)

Comment: Um, that site doesn't include your sample text anywhere.  There are zero instances of _"Tōkyō ni hikkoshite, go-nen ni naru"_ (in either romaji or kanji+kana).  The closest I see is 「東京【とうきょう】から栃木【とちぎ】に引【ひ】っ越【こ】して来【き】てから、もう５年【ごねん】も経【た】つのかぁ」.  That phrasing includes the ~てから, and does not omit the から.

Comment: I don't think so. verb-てから means after *what have you done*. て-form could be interpreted as **because**.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65625/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52228/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a Japanese.
you can use "Toukyou ni hikkoshite kara, go-nen ni naru" as well as "Toukyou ni hikkoshite, go-nen ni naru"
this type of sentence is used when you want to show the "time lapse".

"て" of "家族に会えなくて、寂しいです"
-> this sentence show a reason.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you trying to study English by this website? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: No, I study English on youtube channel 'engVid' and Books every time.